# Filtragem por período em inputs do tipo data

Tags: javascript, html5

Tenho um sistema onde possuo um `<input type="date">` e preciso filtrá-lo, para trazer no calendário apenas as datas de 3 meses atrás e do mês atual

Eu estava utilizando os atributos `min` e `max` para teste, pois eles são valores fixos, e funcionava:

```html
<input type="date" name="dateIni" min="2013-12-01" max="local">
```

Porém, preciso alterar manualmente toda vez que vira o mês. Como automatizar isso?

Comment: A pergunta está pouco clara para mim. Você quer dizer um input type date com calendário (HTML5) e que quer limitar a escolha possivel de datas para max 3 meses antes do dia actual?

Comment: Qual é o plugin de calendário que você está utilizando? Poste um exemplo de código para podermos ajudar! xD

Comment: Isso. Segue o exemplo. Date: <input type="date" name="dateIni" min="2013-12-01" max="local">

Comment: Só para deixar claro, você quer que ao carregar a página o `min` seja setado para `data_atual - 3 meses`?

Comment: Sim e a max a data de hoje.

Comment: Fiz um update ao código. Era essa a função que queria? Funciona para mim no Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente assim:

```js
function decimas(n){
    return n > 9 ? "" + n: "0" + n;
}
function getDate(m) {
    var data = new Date();
    var diffAno = 0;
    var mesAnterior = data.getMonth() - (m === undefined ? 1 : m - 1);
    if (mesAnterior < 1) {
        mesAnterior = mesAnterior + 12;
        diffAno = -1;
    }
    mesAnterior = decimas(mesAnterior);
    var diaAnterior = decimas(data.getDate());
    return (data.getFullYear() + diffAno) + '-' + mesAnterior + '-' + diaAnterior;
}


document.querySelector('input[name=dateIni]').setAttribute("min", getDate(3));
document.querySelector('input[name=dateIni]').valueAsDate  = new Date();
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/8fvkG/)

Tenha em conta que `input type date` é +/- recente (HTML5) e que muitos browsers não reconhecem essa tag. Talvez melhor usar uma bibleoteca que tenha um date picker separado.

Acrescentei a função `decimas()` porque a recomendação da W3C é usar dois digitos na data.

Comment: @HaoneNakano, este script lê a data do dia actual e retira 3 meses. Depois aplica a data ao input